# Has The USPS / APWU Ever Had A Strike Since 1970?

Tags: united-states, labour-history, mail, postal-history

Here in Canada we presently have the CUPW engaged in a strike which is disrupting mail delivery.

I talked to one of my friends in the US, and he was surprised to hear of a strike. Apparently they don't have strikes there for the mail service, or he's never heard of one happening.

[image: 1970s APWU Strike]

I have been able to look up a major national strike in 1970, and I see the AUPW is providing some support for the CUPW strike, however I have been having trouble finding information on any other strikes.

[image: AUPW supporting CUPW strike]

I found this:

> But unlike the UPS and Canada Post situation, federal law prohibits postal and federal employees from striking.
>
> While the APWU technically states, “The APWU believes that the right
> to strike is an inalienable right of all American workers,” the impact
> of such an illegal work action could be disastrous in a political
> climate where the USPS is already under fire.[3](https://esellercafe.com/update-usps-postal-worker-contract-negotiations/)

I find it surprising if it's never happened in 48 years. Have there really not been any, or am I just failing to find them? I would have thought there'd be a nice list somewhere of USPS strikes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in 1978, for a five day wildcat. 125 workers were sacked. http://www.robinsonlibrary.com/social/industries/labor/disputes/78postal.htm